# How to print from object into same output thread as Capybara/Cucumber

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, testing, cucumber, capybara

Whenever I use a `puts` statement inside of a class, it gets printed before the step even starts then the usually usual Capybara output will begin to show up below that.

```
    SF-NR-2:work nr$ cucumber --tags @homepage-tests
Using the default profile...
@homepage-tests
Feature: Homepage Tests

TEST PRINT
  #### Homepage Test
  @bvt
  Scenario: Homepage loads in portrait mode # features/web/homepage.feature:7
    Given I go to the homepage
TEST PRINT
    And the homepage loads
1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m5.041s
```

I added 
    `puts "TEST PRINT"` to each step, but it prints before each step. If i pull the `puts "TEST PRINT"` out of the class scope, it will print in the same thread as capybara/cucumber are printing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're seeing from Cucumber is output from the Cucumber formatter(s) you're using.  Calling `puts` inside a step definition calls `puts` on the formatter which will then show it at the correct spot in the output data.  The issue is that if you call `puts` from inside a different object (class in your app for instance) it's actually calling `Kernel#puts` which the cucumber formatter has no clue about.

You may be able to get what you want by writing to the Cucumber logger instead of `Kernel#puts` when in non step definition code by calling something like

```
Cucumber.logger.info 'text to log'`
```